# Re-ranking based on Original and row-specific New Values

Tags: r, dplyr, rank

I have a dataset like the following:

```
a <- structure(list(CSECT = c("001-01", "001-02", "001-03", "001-04", "001-05", "001-06", "001-07", "001-08", "001-09", "001-10"), 
Ht = c(0.341, 0.1244, 0.3, 0.143, 1.265, 0.143, 0.553, 0.132, 2.221, 1.444), 
Ln= c(11, 351, 454, 15, 1446, 138, 9442, 354, 354, 4566)),
.Names = c("CSECT", "Ht", "Ln"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
a$Pr0 <- round(exp(0.1*a$Ht^0.1*a$Ln^0.05),3)
a
    CSECT     Ht   Ln   Pr0
1  001-01 0.3410   11 1.107
2  001-02 0.1244  351 1.115
3  001-03 0.3000  454 1.128
4  001-04 0.1430   15 1.099
5  001-05 1.2650 1446 1.159
6  001-06 0.1430  138 1.111
7  001-07 0.5530 9442 1.161
8  001-08 0.1320  354 1.116
9  001-09 2.2210  354 1.156
10 001-10 1.4440 4566 1.171
```

I want to rank the rows based on `Pred0` [`ties.method=min`].

```
ab1 <- a %>%
    mutate(rank0 = rank(desc(Pr0), ties.method="min"))
ab1
    CSECT     Ht   Ln   Pr0 rank0
1  001-01 0.3410   11 1.107     9
2  001-02 0.1244  351 1.115     7
3  001-03 0.3000  454 1.128     5
4  001-04 0.1430   15 1.099    10
5  001-05 1.2650 1446 1.159     3
6  001-06 0.1430  138 1.111     8
7  001-07 0.5530 9442 1.161     2
8  001-08 0.1320  354 1.116     6
9  001-09 2.2210  354 1.156     4
10 001-10 1.4440 4566 1.171     1
```

I want to rerank the rows based on a new prediction value named as `Pr30`, which is nothing but 30% increase of `Ln` ie `round(exp(0.1*a$Ht^0.1*((a$Ln)*1.30)^0.05),3)`. I like to get a new ranking based on the changed value of that row by keeping all other rows unchanged (ie, keeping same like the original). For example, for row2, the  `Pr30` will be 1.117, it's ranking will be 6 (`rank30` value) instead of 7 (`rank0` value) when compared with the rest `Pr0` values. Here are two examples:

> Row1: `round(exp(0.1*0.3410 ^0.1*(11*1.30)^0.05),3)=1.108`; As only
>   this row will take 30% increase, others are same. The `Pr` values will
>   look like (`1.108`, 1.115, 1.128, 1.099, 1.159, 1.111, 1.161, 1.116,
>   1.156, 1.171). Need to apply rank function. For `row1`, it is still 9.
>
> Row2: `round(exp(0.1*0.1244 ^0.1*(351*1.30)^0.05),3)=1.117`; As only
>   this row will take 30% increase, others are same. The `Pr` values will
>   look like (1.107, `1.117`, 1.128, 1.099, 1.159, 1.111, 1.161, 1.116,
>   1.156, 1.171). Need to apply rank function. For `row2`, the rank has become 6.

Similar will happen for all rows. The final values would be like the following:

```
    CSECT     Ht   Ln   Pr0 rank0 rank30
1  001-01 0.3410   11 1.107     9      9
2  001-02 0.1244  351 1.115     7      6
3  001-03 0.3000  454 1.128     5      5
4  001-04 0.1430   15 1.099    10     10
5  001-05 1.2650 1446 1.159     3      2
6  001-06 0.1430  138 1.111     8      8
7  001-07 0.5530 9442 1.161     2      2
8  001-08 0.1320  354 1.116     6      6
9  001-09 2.2210  354 1.156     4      3
10 001-10 1.4440 4566 1.171     1      1
```

Supporting [google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zbfrv5aEn7xDtI-HZbFncnl0s8ZOOLbOWT1K9yVgoFQ/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: how did you get 1.117??

Comment: Sorry. I had a glitch in the 30% calculation. For second row, it will be `round(exp(0.1*0.1244 ^0.1*(351*1.30)^0.05),3)` or 1.117.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Couldn't you do exactly the same thing you've already done?  i.e. `a$Pr30 <- round(exp(0.1*a$Ht^0.1*((a$Ln)*1.30)^0.05),3);       a <- a %>%
      mutate(rank0 = rank(desc(Pr0), ties.method="min"),
             rank30 = rank(desc(Pr30), ties.method="min"))`

Comment: I need a loop function. The 30% increment with happen to a single row by keeping other rows unchanged. For example, for row 2, the 30% increase will be 1.117. The 10 `Pr` values will look like (1.107, `1.117`, 1.128, 1.099, 1.159, 1.111, 1.161, 1.116, 1.156, 1.171). Notice that only `row2` value is changed. Need to get the rank of row 2 based on the `Pr` values (by keeping only `row2` changed due to 30% increase). The question is: `What will be the new rank if 30% increase happen to a row by keeping other unchanged ?`

Comment: You have two `2's` and then a 3. I guess after two `2's` you will have a `4`. That is the solution I am getting

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function:

```
  fun =function(x,y){
      y[x]=  round(exp(0.1*a$Ht[x]^0.1*(a$Ln[x]*1.30)^0.05),3)
      rank(-y,ties.method = 'first')[x]
    }

 transform(a,rank1 = rank(-Pr0),rank2 = sapply(seq_along(Pr0),fun,Pr0))
    CSECT     Ht   Ln   Pr0 rank1 rank2
1  001-01 0.3410   11 1.107     9     9
2  001-02 0.1244  351 1.115     7     6
3  001-03 0.3000  454 1.128     5     5
4  001-04 0.1430   15 1.099    10    10
5  001-05 1.2650 1446 1.159     3     2
6  001-06 0.1430  138 1.111     8     8
7  001-07 0.5530 9442 1.161     2     2
8  001-08 0.1320  354 1.116     6     6
9  001-09 2.2210  354 1.156     4     4
10 001-10 1.4440 4566 1.171     1     1
```

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for. I need the rank of each row which has each separately experienced 30% increase (with other remaining same). Think about a situation like this: only `Mr. Yellow`'s salary is increased by 30%; What will be his rank among the group with others with no salary increase? The musical chair will go to the next person (for example, `Mr. Green`), what will be his rank with others salary unchanged (including `Mr. Yellow`)?

Comment: I have shared a google spreadsheet here. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zbfrv5aEn7xDtI-HZbFncnl0s8ZOOLbOWT1K9yVgoFQ/edit?usp=sharing